# Maze solving with constraints

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, maze

I know solving mazes is a frequently discussed topic here on Stack Overflow. Here is a problem that might interest you all.

A maze in the form of a n*n matrix will be given as input. Each element would lie between 0-9. A sequence of numbers, each between 0-9 again would also be given. The dimension of the matrix and the sequence array is also known. The question is to find all possible paths in the matrix from (0,0) to (n-1,n-1) that satisfies the given sequence. The path can move down,right or down+right only. Has to be done using threads.

The input and output format are illustrated in the examples given below-

Examples:
    [Example1 http://gowthams.in/etc/1.PNG](http://gowthams.in/etc/1.PNG)
    [Example2 http://gowthams.in/etc/2.PNG](http://gowthams.in/etc/2.PNG)
    [Example3 http://gowthams.in/etc/3.PNG](http://gowthams.in/etc/3.PNG)

Each thread can either print its position (i,j) or update in some sort of data structure to be processed later.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

This is a homework problem and I am allowed to ask for help. I am not looking for code of any sort. I just want a few pointers in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: @MitchWheat I am struck with handling waiting for the threads to return. I have done a similar problem with processes and I just used wait(NULL) to make sure that all processes return before the program moves on. Threads by their very nature are parallel processing, so I am not sure how to do this. I am sure I can implement the code myself once I get a clear picture of how to do this.

Comment: So is this an algorithm question or a threading question? If the latter, posting the algorithm you would use with a single thread might help. Also, all 3 of your examples look the same.

Comment: I corrected the links to the images which were all pointing at the same file.

Comment: @IVlad This is basically an algorithm question. The algorithm happens to use threading. I have done a similar question using process. I have described whatever logic I could think of in the question itself

Comment: Your basic algorithm looks sound, except that it will create an enormous number of threads on large problem instances.  It might be better to add subproblems to a queue (with appropriate locking) and use a fixed number of threads instead of spinning up a new thread each time. Also is the path allowed to go up or left?  If so, you'll need to (a) create 8 child subproblems instead of 3 for each subproblem and (b) track which cells the current subproblem has already visited, to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: I am required to create 3 threads for each element. Part of the problem. Consider a 3-by-3 Identity matrix. Given sequence 1-1-1, I will first match (0,0), then create 3 threads out of which (1,1) will match and create 3 more threads. Finally (2,2) will match and exits with 1. It will start printing the path and move all the way up to (0,0). So, the question is, how do I make sure that the parent thread waits until the child returns. And how do I handle multiple paths?

Comment: @Gowtham give your exact assignment statement. I think there is a slight chance you misinterpret it.

Comment: @Boris Added the exact problem statement to the question. Hope it helps!

Comment: In the second maze there should also be a path that goes through the second `4`, no?

Comment: @interjay No. Because the sequence has a 6 after the 4, not another 4. The path should match the sequence exactly.

Comment: @Gowtham: But it can move from the bottom `2` to the second `4` and from the second `4` to the `6`. Or maybe the intention is that you can only move right, down, or down+right? Because the problem statement doesn't say such a thing.

Comment: @interjay Thanks for pointing that out! I missed it somehow. The question does not specify this, but I am assuming that the we can move to (i+1,j), (i,j+1) or (i+1,j+1)th elements only. (Because the examples given had this assumption)

Comment: My reading of the exact problem description is that up and left moves are allowed, since they are not explicitly prohibited and the common meaning of the word "maze" allows such moves.

Comment: Also (as Boris Strandjev notes in his answer), you're being asked to find whether any path exists, not all possible paths -- i.e. the output of the program should be "Yes" or "No".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the exact statement.

1) This sentence seems pretty disturbing:

> You are expected to create threads for each entry in the matrix to
>   ensure parallel scanning.

Because that means that for matrix NxN you surely need to create N<sup>2</sup> threads, which for me is rather too much.

However your solution is even more dangerous: you want to start checking the routes and for each check create a new thread. This will create **exponential** number of new threads that will be needed in order to solve the task. You for sure will need some sort of optimization: this is called dynamic optimization: you store in the shared memory whether cell `(i,j)` can be used to finish the sequence taken from `idx`th index to the target cell. That way you will never have to solve the same subtask more than once. I suggest you create conditional locks for each such task `[i,j,idx]` and use it in order to tell the threads dependent on it when the child thread finishes.

2)multiple paths are not issue for you: if I read the assignment correctly you are just interested in whether such path exists, but not to find all solutions.

I am not giving exact solution, just directions, as requested. This is also exactly the way I tend to help homeworkers.

Comment: The language of the question is a bit ambiguous. Even though it says that a thread has to be created for each element, it actually need not go that way. In my way, I will be creating three threads per element that return immediately on checking the path. So, as you say, exponential threads might be created. But practically, very few will be created in practice since there will be at the most 2 or 3 paths only. Also, I feel my biggest problem is multiple paths. In the 2nd example you can see the output format. I have no idea how to approach that. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Gowtham: How do you tell there are at most 2 or 3 paths?

Comment: I can't say for sure. I am looking at the average vs. worst case scenarios. Do you know of any standard algorithms that are related to this problem?

Comment: @Gowtham: worst case is for sure: everything is 1s e.g. Then the solutions will be 2^n in count. Standard algorithm will be backtrack with dynamic optimization. However even these standard algorithms can not cope if the task is to print all paths. If it is just to count them, this can be easily achieved for relatively big tables, using exactly the approach i describe above.

Comment: I understand that and hence my confusion. I was thrown off the moment the question asked us to print **all** the paths in the reverse order (yes, all was in bold!) :)

Comment: @Gowtham: then just assume no worst case test case will be given to you and solve as much as you can. You can never improve your algorithm in less complexity than the output.

Comment: True. But I still have no clue how to print both the paths! Suppose there are two paths only. The threads reach the end and start back tracking. All is good if there is only one path. But what if there are two or more? I won't be having any idea about different paths in the threads that have been started after the split of the path. Hence, I won't be knowing how many times to print. To avoid this, I wanted to make sure that each subtree completely prints out its path and then the next one starts. The threads in Path1 will successively print the path, then threads in Path2. Does this sound ok?

Comment: @Gowtham probably you can even afford passing in the whole path prefix to the new thread. Btw if you need to print dynamic optimization will do you no good.

Comment: I'll try to work on it for a few hours and post back. A big thanks to everyone for helping out!

Comment: @Gowtham: You say "the question asked us to print all the paths in the reverse order (yes, all was in bold!)", but nowhere does that appear in the "exact problem definition" that you supplied -- in fact it quite clearly asks for a yes or no answer, **not** all the paths!

Comment: @j_random_hacker The examples I have given here are also part of the statement. You can see that the output clearly shows two different paths on two different lines. I have edited the original question now to include that line also.

Comment: @Gowtham: I wish you hadn't omitted that sentence when you first added the "exact problem statement" to your post, since doing that just confused things! Anyway, you can adapt Boris's DP approach by recording *how many* ways you can complete a solution from state `[i, j, idx]` instead of *whether* you can complete a solution from there.  Let me know if you need another hint...

Comment: @j_random_hacker Sorry for the confusion. Honest mistake. I am not sure how to implement Boris's method. Should I create a secondary array to store the conditional locks? I feel this is somewhat similar to a Breadth First Search. Is this right?

Comment: Gosh this is difficult @j_random_hacker: this will only print the number, but not the paths themselves, i.e. will not solve the problem entirely. @ Gowtham: BFS is also widely based on DP, however this is not BFS as long as you are not examining the matrix in layers.

Comment: Upvoted all useful comments and accepted Boris's answer because he has put some effort into this. I will try to clarify the question with my instructor and get back to you. Thanks once again!

Comment: I'm sorry, @Boris is right -- my suggestion will help you efficiently calculate the number of paths, but of course won't help if you actually need to print out each one!  In this case, as Boris said earlier on, there isn't anything meaningful you can do to speed things up.